# NetworkByte for Monero Stagenet

Tags: light-wallet

We're using the code [here](https://xmr.llcoins.net/) to generate XMR addresses by providing our own mnemonic.

The website above uses `networkByte = 12` for `Monero Mainnet` and `networkByte = 35` for `Monero Testnet`.

But I was wondering if anyone knew what the `networkByte` is for `Monero Stagenet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stagenet address network bytes are defined in decimal in the file https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/3ad4ecd4ff52f011ee94e0e80754b965b82f072b/src/cryptonote_config.h

```
uint64_t const CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 24;
uint64_t const CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_INTEGRATED_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 25;
uint64_t const CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_SUBADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 36;
```

In hex these numbers are 18, 19, 24 respectively.