# Base58 prefix, network id and wallet address prefix

Tags: address, network

The question [NetworkByte for Monero Stagenet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10147/networkbyte-for-monero-stagenet/10148#10148) gave me the impression that, there's a relation between **ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX** and **NETWORK_ID**, defined in `src/cryptonote_config.h`

If it is so, I can't find it. Anyone care to elaborate?

And how is it related to the public address prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NETWORK_ID is a 16 byte identifier that allows Monero nodes to identify themselves to other nodes, in order to prevent different Monero networks (e.g. mainnet vs stagenet) from accidentally talking to each other. It has nothing directly to do with wallet addresses, although there are different wallet address prefixes designed for use on different networks.

The web site you've linked to uses the the separate term "Network Byte", and shows the hex representations of what src/cryptonote_config.h defines using decimal numbers instead.

E.g. a network byte of 0x12 in hex is the number 18 in decimal, which is why the web site you've linked defaults to the value 12 and the cryptonote_config.h defines the value as `CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 18`;

Comment: I get the NETWORK_ID

`0x12 ,0x30,,,,,, 0xA1, 0x10`, `0x12 ,0x30,,,,,, 0xA1, 0x12`, `0x12 ,0x30,,,,,, 0xA1, 0x12`

That make sense. 

I'm thinking it's not just some random numbers, so where does they come from?


 CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 18;
 CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_INTEGRATED_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 19;
 CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_SUBADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 42;


 CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 53;
 CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_INTEGRATED_ADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 54;
 CRYPTONOTE_PUBLIC_SUBADDRESS_BASE58_PREFIX = 63;


How were these specific numbers choosen?

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK The NETWORK_ID is arbitrarily chosen. The wallet address prefixes are also arbitrarily chosen, but care is taken to ensure that the choice is such that a consistent first character appears in the base58 address that is generated for each prefix, so that they are easily human identifiable without having to do the math to convert the base58 back into hex to check.

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK Btw you might be guessing that network byte means the first byte of the network_id. But that can't be the case, because the network byte is different for different networks, but the network_id starts with 0x12 regardless of the network.